# Garbled utf-8 QString when reading network reply

Tags: qt, utf-8, blackberry-10

I am building a BlackBerry 10 application and I am using the QT libraries. However I got some character encoding issues and I was wondering if you might have a clue as how to solve this.

I have the following data that gets send to me via a web service.

```
{"title":"Seconde Guerre mondiale - Wikipédia","content":"Théâtre européen     L’Europe au 1er septembre 1939   Après s’être assuré de ne pas risquer une guerre avec l’URSS en signant le Pacte germano-soviétique, Hitler lance ses armées sur la Pologne, l...","favicon":"http://fr.m.wikipedia.org//bits.wikimedia.org/favicon/wikipedia.ico"}
```

If I wireshark it, the raw data is:

```
[truncated] {"title":"Seconde Guerre mondiale - Wikip\303\251dia","content":"Th\303\251\303\242tre
```

However when I parse this using the following code:

```
void WebpageFetcher::onPageRequestFinished(QNetworkReply* networkReply)
{
    qDebug() << "WebpageFetcher:: onPageRequestFinished";
    QByteArray content = networkReply->readAll();
    qDebug() << QString::fromUtf8(content.data(), content.size());
}
```

I get this result:

```
"{"title":"Seconde Guerre mondiale - WikipÃ©dia","content":"ThÃ©Ã¢tre europÃ©en Lâ€™Europe au 1er septembre 1939   AprÃ¨s sâ€™Ãªtre assurÃ© de ne pas risquer une guerre avec lâ€™URSS en signant le Pacte germano-soviÃ©tique, Hitler lance ses armÃ©es sur la Pologne, l...","favicon":"http://fr.m.wikipedia.org//bits.wikimedia.org/favicon/wikipedia.ico"}"
```

Not exactly what I am looking for. Does anyone have a clue? My browsers seem to be able to interpret the characters in this JSON reply perfectly.

Comment: May be the string itself is correct, but `qDebug()` output is invalid? Try to use the string somewhere else (e.g. assign it to a QLabel).

Comment: Those titles are displayed in the application (in a label), but are showing the same incorrect data.

Comment: Do you do anything else with the string (concatenating, etc.) except for putting it into the label?

Comment: Nothing is done to the string. Seems like the characters are being interpreted as Windows-1252 instead of UTF-8, at least according to this page: [link](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html)

Comment: Maybe try setCodecForCStrings before you read the data, and setting the codec to UTF-8. You only need to do the following once.  


`QTextCodec *utf8Codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"); QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(utf8Codec);`

Comment: Still no luck. Those who want to try can find the web service at this [link](http://beread.azurewebsites.net/?url=http://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seconde_Guerre_mondiale)

Comment: Solution found. Just like @Riateche said qDebug()'s output was invalid and I made an error when assigning it to a QLabel that I did fromUtf8 again causing the garbage symbols.